# gwt suggestbox doesn't hide on page scroll

Tags: java, html, gwt, suggestbox

I've created a suggest box and generated HTML page with huge text, so I can scroll. 
1. Show suggest list
2. Scroll page

The popup box with suggestion list moves with scrolled page, but I want that it will neither hide when page scrolls nor move with page.

As I understand that suggest popup has absolute position. But is there some non css solution.

---

Answer to:

I've tried add scroll handler to Window, but I've found out that handle only event when I have [image: two scrolls] and right of them moves, only in this case. If I have one scroll to scroll page like in case with large text - nothing invokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing a `SuggestBox` you can provide your own `SuggestOracle`, `TextBox` and `SuggestionDisplay`. `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` can be used to hide suggestion list. You can do it in `Window.scrollHandler`.

Here is the code:

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();
oracle.add("one");
oracle.add("two");
oracle.add("three");

TextBox box = new TextBox();
final DefaultSuggestionDisplay display = new DefaultSuggestionDisplay();

SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle, box, display);

Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        display.hideSuggestions();
    }
});
```

Note, that you need to use `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` - see documentation on **deprecated [hideSuggestionList](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html#hideSuggestionList())** method.

I hope that the example explains it all.

I've also checked that if you don't use own `SuggestionDisplay` it uses `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` anyway. So you can do it even simpler.

```
((DefaultSuggestionDisplay) suggestBox.getSuggestionDisplay()).hideSuggestions();
```

---

**EDIT:**

If not the whole window is scrolled but only content of some panel, you can add a `ScrollHandler` to the panel:

```
panel.addDomHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        ((DefaultSuggestionDisplay) suggestBox.getSuggestionDisplay()).hideSuggestions();
    }
}, ScrollEvent.getType());
```

Comment: see addition in ask

Comment: @DmitriyAltsyvanovich - try to add a `ScrollHandler` to the container - see my edit.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found correct div with scroll and added handler to it - it fixes all my trouble)